how i pass data session from page 1 to page 2
im new in laravel 9 and i cant complet this test
web.php
Route::get('contact', 'App\Http\Controllers\controllerPage@contact');

Route::post('contact', 'App\Http\Controllers\controllerPage@saveData');

Route::get('about', 'App\Http\Controllers\controllerPage@about');

controller
    public function contact(){
        
        return view('contact');
        
       
    }
    
    public function saveData(Request $request){
        
        $request->session()->put('name', $request->nameFull);
        
        
    }
    
    public function about(Request $request) {
        $name = $request->session()->get('name', 'no data');
        
        return view('about', ['name' => $name]);
        
        
    }

view
    <h2>Welcom to our site : {{ $name }}</h2
the data from session not show in about view
i want show session data['name'] from page contact to page about

What is SESSION_DRIVER you have in .env? If array - change it to file.

Yes is it BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
